# Different definitions of Mathias forcing are equivalent

Tags: set-theory, forcing

The Mathias Forcing is defined using increasing sequences and I wondered if it would be forcing equivalent if one omits this condition. So, for a free ultrafilter $U$ define
\begin{align*}
   \mathbb{M}_U &= \{ (s,X) \mid X \in U, s \text{ is an increasing finite sequence} \}\\
   {\mathbb{M}_U}^* &= \{ (s,X) \mid X \in U, s \text{ is a finite sequence} \}
\end{align*}
with the usual ordering.

I was able to show that if $f$ is a Mathias real for ${\mathbb{M}_U}^*$, then the enumeration of $\text{range}(f)$ is a Mathias real for $\mathbb{M}_U$. But I got stuck in the other direction, because for example if $f$ is a Mathias real for $\mathbb{M}_U$, then $f$ is necessarily strictly increasing, but any Mathias real $g$ for ${\mathbb{M}_U}^*$ has properties like containing arbitrarily long decreasing sequences, so I do not have an idea how to define such a $g$ from $f$, so I would appreciate a hint how to do the construction if it is even possible.

Comment: I have never seen this before, but try enumerating all finite sequences, and using the generic real to decode the sequence of finite sequences. Not sure if it would work, though.

Comment: Just as a reference, Canjar used the increasing definition in his paper "Mathias Forcing which does not add dominating reals" and there are papers referencing Canjar's work, for example "Mathias-Prikry and Laver-Prikry type forcing" by Hrusak and Minami which use the other definition, so I figured they should be forcing equivalent. I will play around a bit with your idea later.

Comment: Doesn't the arbitrary finite sequence real somehow code a Cohen real, via the lengths of its decreasing parts e.g.? Then they are in general not equivalent. Btw, for me Mathias forcing has a finite set as a stem. This is certainly equivalent to the incresing sequence version. I have never seen the other version before.

Comment: Turns out I misread the finite sets as finite sequences in the second reference, so the definition is as Jonathan proposed, I reformulated the question whether the two definitions are equivalent without the claim that it is somewhere defined this way.

Comment: @Jonathan Correct my if I am wrong, but if there are no selective ultrafilters, then every Mathias-Prikry forcing adds Cohen reals, so your suggestion would only show that it is consistent with ZFC that the definitions are not forcing equivalent, right?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, if you force with a non-selective ultrafilter (or was it non-$p$-point, or something?) you collapse the continuum to be countable, in which case you definitely add a lot of Cohen reals.

Comment: @AsafKaragila How so? The forcing is always ccc (in fact $\sigma$-centered). Maybe you're thinking about the version with co-ideals.

Comment: @Jonathan: That must be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Jonathan for the hint, I will elaborate on his comment:

We can show that ${M_U}^*$ always adds a Cohen real. Let $\mathbb{C} = \text{Fn}(\omega, \omega \setminus \{ 0 \})$. Given a Mathias real $f_G$ for ${M_U}^*$ we can decode it to a real $g: \omega \to \omega \setminus \{ 0 \}$ by evaluating the lengths of decreasing sequences in $f_G$. We write $f_G$ codes $g$. We can define $t$ codes $s$ for finite sequences in the same way. Now, define
$$
t ^\frown N \text{ codes } s \iff t \text{ codes } s \text{ and } N > \max(t)
$$
This has the benefit that if $t ^\frown N$ codes $s$ and $f_G \supset t ^\frown N$, then $s \supset g$ as $f_G$ cannot extend the decreasing sequence at the end of $t$ due to $N$ breaking the decreasing sequence.

Now, let $D\in V$ be dense in $\mathbb{C}$ then define
$$
D' = \{ (t ^\frown N, X) \mid X \in U \text{ and } \exists s \in D \text{ such that } t ^\frown N \text{ codes } s \} \in V
$$
We show that $D'$ is dense in ${M_U}^*$, so let $(t,X) \in {M_U}^*$. Then $t$ codes some $s$, so choose $s' \in D$ such that $s' \supseteq s$. But $X$ is infinite, so we can extend $t$ to $t'$ with elements of $X$ such that $t'$ codes $s'$ and choose some $N \in X$ such that $N > \max(t')$. Then $(t' ^\frown N, X) \in D'$ and extends $(t,X)$.

Finally, choose $(t ^\frown N, X) \in G \cap D'$ and choose $s \in D$ such that $t ^\frown N$ codes $s$. Then $f_G \supset t ^\frown N$, so $s \supset g$, which shows that $g$ is a Cohen real.

Now, if $U$ is a selective ultrafilter, then $\mathbb{M}_U$ does not add Cohen reals, so they cannot be forcing equivalent. However, there need not be selective utrafilters, so this does not show that in such models the two definitions are not equivalent.

Comment: By the way, I think it shouldn't be too hard show that in fact $M_U^*$ is forcing equivalent to $M_U \times \mathbb{C}$. To see this go exactly the other way by letting the $\mathbb{C}$ part encode a specific way to enumerate the stem of the $M_U$ part. Then this should be a dense embedding. Maybe I am wrong somewhere, I didn't check it carefully.